# Magento 2 Home page Product images

Tags: product-images

I have quite a few products in my store which have images on their product pages, but on my home page the images don't show in the tiles?

Is there a file missing, or is there a refresh I need to do?

For example, on my current home page:
https://www.shelburnecountrystore.com/
The fourth tile is No Image, yet when you go to the page:
https://www.shelburnecountrystore.com/80mm-glass-fog-white-balls.html
The image shows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regenerating thumbnails?

You should try using the image resize command to pre-generate all necessary resizes.

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

This command gets all the images sizes that have been defined in the theme XML and pregenerates the images in their correct folders.

You can also check the command documentation for more information http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html